# Javascript populating hidden fields on mouseover - Before click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Looking for a solution to another problem I cam across the ability to run javascript on mouseover

I'd like to run this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function myPayment()
{

var value = document.mortgagecalc.value_input.value;
var rate = document.mortgagecalc.rate_input.value;
var term = document.mortgagecalc.term_input.value;
var deposit = document.mortgagecalc.deposit_input.value;
var fee = document.mortgagecalc.fee_input.value;
var totalloan = ((value + fee) - deposit) * 1 + rate;
var totalinterest = (totalloan * 1 + rate) - totalloan;
var months = (term * 12);
var repay = totalloan / months;
var interest = totalinterest / months;

// Calculate mortgage payment and display result
document.getElementById('repay_input').value = repay;
document.getElementById('interest_input').value = interest;
}
}
```

When a user mouses over my submit button

When the script runs I'd like it to populate these fields which are then included in the form action

```
<input type="hidden" name="repay" id="repay_input" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="interest" id="interest_input" value="">
```

Right now it doesn't seem to work but this may be because I've missed a small thing or it just won't work entirely

Thank you - If anyone has a better idea on how to achieve my aim please let me know, I've tried PHP but no joy

Button for clarity

```
<button class="col-sm-4 enter-button" type="submit" name="submit" onmouseover="return myPayment()" value="Calculate">Calculate Payments</button>
```

Update:

I tweaked the javascript and the button but then missed off naming the form to match the reference in the JS

Also my mortgage calculations were WAY off due to the way the form collects % rate

Comment: How are are u binding the mouseover event? its hard to debug when all the pieces are not included in the post.. also plz try to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: I don't see any usage of `mouseover` in your code. Where exactly to you have it?

Comment: @SajjanSarkar - Added

Comment: @Dekel - Added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your function outside of jQuery's `document.ready` wrapper, and your button only needs to look like this:

```js
function myPayment()
{
  var value = document.mortgagecalc.value_input.value;
  var rate = document.mortgagecalc.rate_input.value;
  var term = document.mortgagecalc.term_input.value;
  var deposit = document.mortgagecalc.deposit_input.value;
  var fee = document.mortgagecalc.fee_input.value;
  var totalloan = ((value + fee) - deposit) * 1 + rate;
  var totalinterest = (totalloan * 1 + rate) - totalloan;
  var months = (term * 12);
  var repay = totalloan / months;
  var interest = totalinterest / months;

  // Calculate mortgage payment and display result
  document.getElementById('repay_input').value = repay;
  document.getElementById('interest_input').value = interest;
}
```

```html
<button onmouseover="myPayment()" ...></button>
```

Comment: Those changes don't seem to have worked - Do I need the script to be at a specific location eg below the form?

Comment: @Frsti No because it is a function declared as `function name() { ... }` it should be able to go anywhere. Put the function in its own `<script></script>` element inside the head.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the chrome console - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value_input' of undefined

Apparently it doesn't like the use of value? Changed to "loan" but still getting the error

Comment: Ok caught the error, I hadn't named the form that the JS was referencing and I'm getting numbers in my fields which is the best I've done all day - Thank you so much